# Error with Loadbalancing, Websockets and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker, socket.io

I have two NodeJS application with socket.io, which sits behind a local (docker) NGINX loadbalancer. Wenn only one application is up everything works fine. When I add the second I get the following error on every second reload or so.

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://[HOST]/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=9CmO27cJsdmqMwwXAAAK' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

here my NGINX config:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    upstream myhost {
        least_conn;
        server 192.168.99.1:3333;
        server 192.168.99.1:4444;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name         [HOST];
        ssl_certificate     server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key server.key;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_pass http://myhost;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have `socket.io` set up to support multiple nodes, in which case the server on port 3333 might get requests/frames related to connections set up by the server on port 4444 (and vice versa) which will cause problems (because a connection set up by 3333 is unknown to 4444).

There are various solutions outlined here: https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/

Comment: Thanks, but I've setup websockets with and without multiple-nodes setup

Comment: @refextu which method did you use?

Comment: redis: `io.adapter(redis({ host: '192.168.99.1', port: 6379 }));` and the connections works really well. When I'll start one app with a not loadbalanced port and emit an event. It will be pushed to the connected client on the loadbalanced app.

Comment: But you also need to make sure that connections are made to the correct load-balanced endpoint (on the page I linked to, they suggest using `ip_hash` in the NGINX upstream config). I.e.: clients should always be speaking to the same upstream.

Comment: Ok, I made two changes:
* adding map from: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html
* switching to ip_hash

This combination seems to work. Thank you